# Get title of Facebook videos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get the title of the Facebook video using PHP.

I googled around and could not find any reference so I started trying with Facebook Graph API.

I followed using the sample given in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

The issue is it requires session tokens in order the get the information.

The code I used:

```
<?php 
require_once('/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');

use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/10154392917806729'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

print_r($response);

?>
```

The /10154392917806729 is the video ID. It is showing "Undefined variable: session" error.

My guess is I must get the session tokens etc in order for this to work.

Is there any other simplified way? I only want to get the video title given the video url.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please check session variable scope or is this variable has value here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a facebook application at developers.facebook.com and use the client_id, secret from the same with an access token to create a new Facebook session

eg:

```
 \FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($client_id,$client_secret);

        $session = new FacebookSession($token);
```

if you create a session using this code before your segment of code. It should work fine